# My published android app in google play bring buy instead of install before buy

Tags: java, android

I publish an app with ads and in-app purchase, but i discover i can only buy, what am expecting is to install and click on button to purchase. Please how can i go about it, should i create another app with free and another app with purchase. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you not made IN-app purchases. You made the app cost money.

Comment: Thank you for your comment please is their any reference i can archieve that please